# Why is the static variable not assigned to the value returned by the static method?

Tags: java, static

I tried to run the below code

```
static int j = f();
static int i = 10;
static int f(){
    return i;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("i="+i);
    System.out.println("j="+j);
}
```

It produces the output as

```
i=10
j=0
```

Can anyone explain why is j=0 ?

Comment: Because the static variables are initialised in declaration order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i = 10` runs *after* the call to `f()` (because that's the order you wrote it in in source)

Comment: An exact duplicate of another question. Flag the question next time as a duplicate